# AWS TimeStream Python SDK: Cannot create a correct client object

Tags: python, aws-sdk, amazon-timestream

Based on AWS TimeStream SDK documentation for Python, I have the following code:

```py
import boto3

def list_databases(self):
        print("Listing databases")
        try:
            result = self.client.list_databases(MaxResults=5)
            self._print_databases(result['Databases'])
            next_token = result.get('NextToken', None)
            while next_token:
                result = self.client.list_databases(NextToken=next_token, MaxResults=5)
                self._print_databases(result['Databases'])
                next_token = result.get('NextToken', None)
        except Exception as err:
            print("List databases failed:", err)

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='superuser', region_name='eu-west-1')
query_client = session.client('timestream-query')

list_databases(query_client)
```

The authentication for my user `superuser` seems to work fine, but the `boto3` session used for my `query_client` does not have a client object:

```
Listing databases
List databases failed: 'TimestreamQuery' object has no attribute 'client'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This argument name in this method is likely a mistake:

```
# this name is discouraged in non-OO code:
def list_databases(self):
```

`self` is typically used in object oriented python code, which is not the case here.

Rename it as follows:

```
# this is better:
def list_databases(client):
```

Then, remove any mention of `self` in the body of the function, for example:

```
# this is incorrect:
result = self.client.list_databases(MaxResults=5)
```

should be:

```
# this should work:
result = client.list_databases(MaxResults=5)
```

Comment: You are correct, thank you very much. It's strange that the function was wrong because this comes directly from the AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/code-samples.list-db.html

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it now works. Indeed that documentation is misleading. I guess they meant to suggest to put that method inside a python class, although that is not explicitly mentioned anywhere.